# Custom button on edit product page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

So I have added a custom button and onclick function to the edit product page, the button appears fine. I have set an onclick function, and the code for this runs when the edit product page is loaded, but not when I click the button. I only need it to run if the button is clicked. I have overridden the Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit.php and added the following code:

Add to the end of the peraperlayout function:

```
$this->_product = $this->getProduct();
            $this->setChild('printbarcode_button',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                ->setData(array(
                'label'     => 'Print Barcode',
                'onclick'   => $this->getPrintLabelUrl()
            ))
        );
```

added:

```
public function getBarcodeButtonHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('printbarcode_button');
    }
```

amended:

```
public function getDuplicateButtonHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('duplicate_button') . $this->getChildHtml('printbarcode_button');
    }
```

and the function I have wrote that I want to run on click, and not on load, as it is doing now:

```
public function getPrintLabelUrl()
    {
        //This downloads a PDF on demand        

        try {
            //get param
            $productId = $this->getProductId();
            $qty = 1;
            Mage::log('Trying to autoprint barcodes, SKU: ' . $productId . " Qty: " . $qty, null, 'custom_log.log');
            //create pdf & download
            $obj = mage::getModel('AdvancedStock/Pdf_BarcodeLabels');

            $pdf = $obj->getPdf(array($productId => $qty));

            $fileName = 'barcode.pdf';
            mage::helper('ClientComputer')->printDocument($pdf->render(), $fileName, 'Barcodes : print barcode');
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            die("Error auto sending PDF to printer: " . $ex->getMessage() . '<p>' . $ex->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }
```

Any help/guidance would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function `getPrintLabelUrl` should actually return an Url, but not do any actions. 
So you have to create a controller, then move Pdf generation logic to the controller and make function `getPrintLabelUrl` to return url path of your new controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Neklo,

Yeah, that is the correct way of doing it.

However, I ended up doing it in a bit of a rough way. I put the PDF creation code inside an if statement on if a GET parameter has been set, and changed the onclick function to put the GET parameter onto the end of the current url and reload the page. It works for what I need. As far as I can tell, it doesn't have any adverse effects

Thanks for your help! Will probably re-write it in the above way in the future.